# why changing wcf endpoint address in code seems doesn't work?

Tags: wcf

We have some really legacy wcf code and we got a strange problem:

```
        WCFChartService.ChartServiceClient service = new WCFChartService.ChartServiceClient();
        using (new OperationContextScope(service.InnerChannel))
        {
            service.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(
                "http://mypreprodsite.net/MyChartService.svc");

            service.UpdateChartTemplate(
                xxxx);
        }
```

In web.config, we have:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IChartService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://myprodsite.net/MyChartService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IChartService"
        contract="WCFChartService.IChartService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IChartService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Above code throws some error, so I debugged this, and turned out if in my web.config I have this everything will be fine

```
<endpoint address="http://mypreprodsite.net/MyChartService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IChartService"
            contract="WCFChartService.IChartService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IChartService" />
```

The function change in wcf has only been deployed to preprod site, so looks like in my testing project, changing url directly in service.Endpoint.Address doesn't work as I expected.

As I moved away from old wcf code years ago (only randomly got assigned to look this one), can someone explain why? If I set **service.Endpoint.Address="localhost:8049/MyChartService.svc"** and my local machine does get called, so I am rather confused.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to specify endpoint addresses for a service in WCF. You can specify an absolute address for each endpoint associated with the service or you can provide a base address for the ServiceHost of a service and then specify an address for each endpoint associated with this service that is defined relative to this base address.

Here is the reference: [Specifying an Endpoint Address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/specifying-an-endpoint-address).

Comment: but why setting it in code seems doesn't work?

Comment: The format of the URL you specified is wrong, no protocol is included, and there is a code to specify the endpoint address in the reference.